# Constructing a float32 value from four uint8 bytes

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to read depth values from the topic `/camera/depth/image_rect_color`. The message is of the type `sensor_msgs/Image` and prints out 8 bit data (`uint8`) as elements of an image array. Since the image is encoded as `32FC1`, I need to combine four of these elements to obtain depth information of a single pixel.  A [stack overflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3991478/building-a-32bit-float-out-of-its-4-composite-bytes-c) contains the following code:

```
float f;
uchar b[] = {b3, b2, b1, b0};
memcpy(&f, &b, sizeof(f));
return f;
```

Is this the right approach to construct a `float32` value from 4 bytes of `uint8` values, **without any data loss** ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240350/constructing-a-float32-value-from-four-uint8-bytes/) by [skr_robo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25555/skr_robo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 178 on 2016-07-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Instead of trying to do that conversion by hand for each pixel, I recommend that you use the [cv_bridge](http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge) package to convert your `sensor_msgs/Image` into a `cv::Mat`, which should be easier to use. The [cv_bridge tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge/Tutorials/UsingCvBridgeToConvertBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImages) is probably a good place to start, but obviously you'll need to change the image encoding parameters.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [skr_robo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25555/skr_robo/) on 2016-07-25**:
My intention is to find out any obstacle within 5m of a zed stereo camera. The data is basically depth value. I am planning to avoid using openCV. Is there any reference for data conversion by hand? I wouldn't mind writing additional lines of code for that.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-07-25**:
The canonical reference is the implementation of the `sensor_msgs/Image` to `cv::Mat` conversion function that's underneath all of the cv_bridge conversions: https://github.com/ros-perception/vision_opencv/blob/e548e37cba1b8d473be5836cbb37d7ed5abdd7ac/cv_bridge/src/cv_bridge.cpp#L249-L298